# How to resize canvas using his height and width attribute on every time it's get resize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

I have the below canvas which is getting updated whenever the div gets resized.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize',function()
{
    let mapwidth = $('.canvas').attr("width")
    let mapHeight = $('.canvas').attr("height")

    console.log(mapwidth ,mapHeight)
    

    $('.canvas').css("width",mapwidth);
    $('.canvas').css("height",mapHeight);
});
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvas" tabindex="0" width="511" height="333" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
<br>
<canvas class="canvas" tabindex="0" width="232" height="1333" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

but it's not working somehow I am only getting 0 0

1. my question is how I get the current canvas height and width in the
   inline style.
2. now the same height and width get applied on all the canvas, but I want different for all canvas base on their attribute

Comment: I get `511, 333`, not `0, 0`.

Comment: that's on first load not on every time resize

Answer (score 0):

So, since you want to do this for `.each()` `.canvas` class element, you are going to have to use the jQuery selector (`$(".canvas")`) to select all those classes, then iterate over them with the `.each()` method.

Example:

```
$(".canvas").each(function()
{
    console.log(this.height, this.width);
});
```

The above will print the current width and height for each `.canvas` element.

Furthermore, you can add logic based on the attributes you want, example:

```
$(".canvas").each(function()
{
    console.log(this.height, this.width);
    if ($(this).attr("height") > 50)
    {
        console.log("Greater than 50.");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Not greater than 50.");
    }
    // You can also use the ternary operator to shorten the above if statement to:
    // $(this).attr("height") > 50? console.log("Greater than 50."): console.log("Not greater than 50.");
});
```

Below is an example of the first code snippet - you'll have to resize the page for it to do anything, of course.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize',function()
{
    $(".canvas").each(function()
    {
      console.log(this.height, this.width, "these are the values set for the physical canvas space")
      $(this).css("height", 100 + "px")
      console.log(this.style.height, this.style.width, "these are the physical inline styles for each of the canvas elements; notice width hasn't been set yet.");
      // there are 3 ways you can set width - the first one is the same way we set height:
      // $(this).css("width", 100 + "px");
      // the second will let you set the !important flag, if you need to (which is my preference):
      // this.style.setProperty("width", value);
      // this.style.setProperty("width", value, "important");
      // lastly, you could do (I think):
      // this.style.height = value;
    });
});
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvas" tabindex="0" width="511" height="333" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
<br>
<canvas class="canvas" tabindex="0" width="232" height="1333" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
```

EDIT 1:

I think that the event listener is being added twice to this code snippet, not because of the code itself, but maybe the SO page runs the snippet before hand to load it?

EDIT 2:
You should have a few option for setting the inline styles - here they are:

- This option -> `$(this).css("width", 100 + "px");`
- This option -> will let you set the !important flag, if you need to (which is my preference)

  - `this.style.setProperty("width", value);` (make sure to include the units)
  - `this.style.setProperty("width", value, "important");` (make sure to include the units)
- I think this is an option for inline styling as well -> `this.style.height = value;` (make sure to include the units)

Comment: How I get the same height and width of current canvas and it will update the same on inline style.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding the beginning of your question your question.

Comment: I want canvas attributes (height and width ) into in same element inline-style.

Comment: Look at edit 2 @MANISHKANVADIYA